# Calculate time copmplexity of the program with DFS algorithm running in a loop in Python

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, depth-first-search

I have implemented a python program based on Graph data structure list implementation and used DFS algorithm for traversing vertex. Below is the time complexity of each method in my program.

O(1) + O(1) + O(n) + ( O(n) * O(V + E) )

V is Vertex and E is Edge.

If someone can help me calculate the above, that will be my whole program time complexity. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Other_arithmetic_operators

Comment: @Gassa not really. I already googled it but couldn't find much useful information.

Comment: And what is `n`?